# How to mock an endpoint that masked the card number in Wiremock?

Tags: wiremock

We have an endpoint that masks card numbers. I want to mock this endpoint with Wiremock. Since it will work for more than one card number, it is not possible for me to prepare a separate mock file for each card. How can I mock this endpoint using a single file? The request sent and the response returned to this request are as follows:

```
Request:
{
    "cardNumber": "1234561234561234"
}
Response:
{
    "maskedCard": "123456******1234"
}
```

I prepared a Wiremock file that works only for 1 card number:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/maskedCard",
        "bodyPatterns": [
            {
                "matchesJsonPath": "[?(@.cardNumber == '1234561234561234')]"
            }
        ]
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "jsonBody": {
            "maskedCard": "123456******1234"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make this work for all incoming card numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the cardNumber attached to the request does not matter, then I would just exclude the bodyPatterns for matching.

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/maskedCard"
    }
```

If you then need to take whatever the cardNumber in the request body is and mask it, I'm not aware of any out of the box solution to do that for you. Instead you'll have to write a Response Transformer to change the unmasked cardNumber to the masked CardNumber. Something like...

```
public class MaskCardNumbers extends ResponseTransformer {

    public String getName() {
        return "MaskCardNumbers";
    }

    @Override
    public Response transform(Request request, Response response, FileSource files, Parameters parameters) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/maskedCard");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(request.getUrl());
        if(matcher.matches()) { 
            // Logic to extract cardNumber - my library of choice is JsonSimple
            JSONObject responseBody = (JSONObject) parser.parse(response.getBodyAsString());
            String cardNumber = responseBody.get("cardNumber").toString();
            
            // Logic to replace cardNumber
            String maskedCard = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < cardNumber.length(); i++) {
                if (i < 6 || i > 11) {
                    maskedCard += cardNumber.charAt(i);
                } else {
                    maskedCard += "*";
                }
            }

            // Create response JSON Object
            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject();
            responseObject.put("cardNumber", maskedCard)

            // Return responseObject
                            return Response.Builder.like(response).but().body(responseBody.toJSONString()).build();
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then need to make sure that [WireMock launches with the transformer attached.](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#registering-extensions) Finally, your mapping would look like:

```
{
    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "/maskedCard"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "jsonBody": {
            "maskedCard": "123456******1234"
        }
    }
}
```

You might need to play around with some specifics, but I think that should get the job done, or at least get you most of the way there.

Comment: Did I properly understand that the suggested solution is to write Java code, compile it, build it, package it, deploy it with WireMock, maintain it in the long run (e.g. version upgrades)? All while also making sure that any dependencies it uses - like the JSON library - isn't in conflict with what WireMock uses (I don't know if that's prevented by some special class loading approach)? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Yes, since it sounds like you require some custom code to perform that masking. WireMock can't anticipate every single use case for transforming responses. There are a good number of out of the box transformers available, but unfortunately, your use case is specific enough that it requires a completely custom transformer. The process I outlined is the standard process for writing, attaching, and maintaining custom transformers. If you think your use case is generic enough that it should be standard, I'd write up an issue in the WireMock github repo.